# Checking if user inputted right character

Tags: arrays, input, char

I am trying to figure out how to make sure a user is inputting the right character. Basically, I want the user to enter c or u. I got it so far that it works until the user enters a phrase beginning with u or c, it still goes through. I want them to only press c or u without any other characters attached to the letter. I figured it has to do with something about arrays, but I am not too educated on arrays. here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char turn;

    printf("Welcome to the game of Sticks. The objective is to pick up the last stick\n\n");
    printf("Please choose who goes first. (u for user and c for computer): ");
    scanf(" %c", &turn);

    while (turn != 'c' && turn != 'u')          //Checking if user inputted c or u
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter u to go first or c for computer to go first!\n");
        scanf(" %c", &turn);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the `==` comparison operator for comparing strings...

Instead use the `strncmp` function, defined in `"string.h"`

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

  char turn[] = "";

  scanf("%c",&turn);      

  while(strncmp(turn,'c',sizeof('c')) != 0) && (strncmp(turn,'u',sizeof('u')) != 0){
    //If User didn't enter c or u
    scanf("%c",&turn);

  }

 return 0;

}
```

Oh and also, always make sure you initialize the variables you define in a function, for example, initialize the `turn` variable by doing something like: `char turn = "";`.

This is to prevent the `turn` variable from being assigned a random value in the memory address.